# When are there countable partitions in a factor's projection lattice?

Tags: operator-algebras, lattice-orders, von-neumann-algebras

Given a non-commutative non-type-I factor $M$, if $P(M)$ denotes the lattice of projections in $M$ (with the usual ordering $x \leq y \iff$ range$(x) \subseteq $ range$(y)$), then every nonzero $x \in P(M)$ has an uncountable antichain of projections below it. (@martin_argerami gave a nice proof of this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608673/von-neumann-algebras-with-uncountable-sets-of-incompatible-projections).)

Since any antichain below $x$ can be extended to a *maximal* antichain below $x$ -- also called a "partition" of $x$ -- there is an uncountable partition of $x$.

**Question: are there cases where some projection $x$ also has a nontrivial *countable* partition in $P(M)$?** (Again, assuming $M$ is a noncommutative non-type-I factor; and nontrivial meaning not the partition consisting just of $x$)

Comment: The definition is confusing to me. It seems that $\{p\}$ is a partition of $p$.

Comment: I meant "antichain *below* $x$" to rule out the trivial case where the antichain is $\{ x \}$ but I will edit the question to make this more explicit.

Comment: I think I've proved that there is no countable nontrivial partition of a type III factor's projection lattice. Given a countable set $\{ x_n \} \subseteq P(M) \setminus \{0,1\}$ of projections, set $y_0 = x_0$ and then iteratively define $y_{n+1}$ by "rotating $y_n$ away from $x_n$". Let $y$ be the strong-operator limit of the $y_n$. If for all $m$ the angles of rotation decrease quickly enough for $n > m$, the $y_n$ cannot "rotate far enough back" for $y$ to meet $x_m$, so $y$ will be a counterexample to $\{ x_n \}$ being a partition. Proof requires some details but they're not very edifying.

Comment: I should say what I mean by "rotating" a projection though. In a type III factor, every projection $x \neq 0,1$ has a partial isometry $V$ whose initial space is $x$'s range, & whose final space is $(1-x)$'s range. $V$ "rotates $x$'s range onto its orthog. complement." Then $\cos(\theta)x + \sin(\theta)V$ is a partial isometry that "rotates $x$ towards its complement by $\theta$ radians"; the projection onto its final space exists in $P(M)$ and can be considered $x$ rotated by $\theta$ radians.